# Where is the Hive metastore warehouse directory path to store database/tables?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, apache-spark-1.5.2

I have installed the *Spark 1.5.2* build with *Hive* on a Linux machine.
The default path for the Hive metastore warehouse directory is: */user/hive/warehouse*.

1. Is this a local path or a path to the *HDFS*? I ask this, because I couldn't search this path in Linux.
2. If it's an *HDFS* path (most likely), then can we access it without having installed *Hadoop* with/without a *Spark* build?

Answer (score 0):

you can create warehouse in local as well in your hive-site.xml put

hive.metastore.warehouse.dir 
        file:///tmp

Answer (score -1):

Yes, /user/hive/warehouse is an HDFS path. You'll need to install and run Hadoop services (at least namenode, secondary namenode, datanode) to make HDFS available.

Comment: not necessary you can run hive with out hadoop refer to my answer below

Answer (score -1):

Type jps and see if all services are running. if running check metastore_db is present in the path /user/hive/warehouse